# validation summary problem

Tags: asp.net, validation, summary

i have a page where i am using validation summary and required field validators. When i click the validation button error message is being dispalyed in both validation summary is showing message written in required field validators. I want to display different message in validation summary and required field validators. 
e.g
validation summary should display "field marked with * are mandatory" and required field validator should display only a "*".

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set your validator's **Text** property to "*". This will be displayed at validator's text when validation fails, and the **ErrorMessage** will be displayed by the validation summary.

Comment: i did that but it also displays * in the validation summary along with the error message of the validation summary

Comment: i only need error message in validation summmary(no *) and only * in required field validator.

Comment: pankaj, you need to set 'display' to 'none' on the validator

Answer (score 1):

Pankaj try this code...

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Error" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <br />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
        DisplayMode="List" />
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Here i have set the DisplayMode property of validation summary to List

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking up how to do this - like I just was - this works for me using MVC4:

**Model:**

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="*")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

**CSS:**

> ```
> .validation-summary-errors ul
> {
>     display: none;
> }
> ```

**View Form:**

> <% using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Contact") ){ %>
>           <%--<%: Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Fields marked * required", new {  @style = "display:none"})%>--%>
>           <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Fields marked * required")%>
>
> ```
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) %>
>             <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
>         </div>
>         <p>
>             <input type="submit" value="Send" />
>         </p>
>     </fieldset>
> <% } %>
> ```