# Required field validator not working on specific page

Tags: asp.net

Below is the code. Validation summary is never displayed.I trie to add validation group but no help.

```
<td style="text-align: left">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtccnum" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td style="text-align: left">
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtccnum" ErrorMessage="Credit Card # Cannot be empty">*
  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True"
    ShowSummary="False" DisplayMode="BulletList" Width="700px" />
<asp:Button ID="btnapply" Text="NEXT" runat="server" OnClick="btnapply_Click" />
```

Comment: Do you know what is being displayed in the validation summary?       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182205/validation-summary-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Page.IsValid flag in button click so it will fire the validations and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Because  ShowSummary="False"

Make ShowSummary ="True"